# How to create a random number generator using Reactor?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I want to simulate measurement data by emitting random numbers repeatedly. I tried to do it with Reactor, but it doesn't produce any output:

```
private static Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Flux<Double> doubleGenerator = Flux.generate(
            () -> random.nextDouble(),
            (ignored, sink) -> {
                sink.next(random.nextDouble());
                return 0.0;
            });
    Flux<Long> timer = Flux.intervalMillis(1000);
    Flux.combineLatest(doubleGenerator, timer, (value, ignored) -> value)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

How can I create a stream of random values with Reactor?

Comment: "but it doesn't work" -->  please describe how it does not work. What did you expect to happen and what happened instead.

Comment: You're right. In this case I don't see any output and the program seems to run infinitely.

Comment: Try switching the order of `doubleGenerator` and `timer` in the call to `combineLatest` and add a Thread.sleep after it to stop the VM from terminating, and you get some result - but it's still not what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this using Reactor 3.1 so `Flux.intervalMillis(long)` has changed to `Flux.interval(Duration)` in my solution below. Essentially I create a Flux that emits a number at an interval (once per second in my case) and then maps that to a random number.

```
final Random random = new Random();
Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .map(pulse -> random.nextDouble())
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

I just did my example in a plain `main()` method, so in order for the Flux to actually be around long enough to emit data, I added that sleep.